# HDKeys Sign Verify

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography, bitcoin

Trying to sign and verify a random string using private keys. I'm Using hdkeys and bip39 packages

Code:

```
const HDkey = require('hdkey')
const bip39 = require('bip39')

const mnemonic = bip39.generateMnemonic()
console.log('You recovery seed phrase: \n'+ mnemonic)

let genkey = HDkey.fromMasterSeed(Buffer.from(mnemonic, 'hex'))
let privKey = genkey.privateKey;
let pubKey = genkey.publicExtendedKey; 

console.log()
console.log('Private Key: ' + privKey)

console.log()
console.log('Public Key: ' + pubKey)

const hash = "Adadadas"
genkey.sign(hash)
hdkey.verify(hash, sign)
```

But there comes an error:

```
if (!cond) throw new Error(msg)                                                                                                                              
             ^                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Error: Expected message to be an Uint8Array
```

I'm new to this.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message describes, the message to be signed should be a `Uint8Array` object with 256-bits (32-bytes) length. You need to hash your message.

```
const message = "Adadadas"
const hash = crypto.createHash('sha256');
hash.update(message);
const hashBuffer = hash.digest();
const hashUint8Array = new Uint8Array(hashBuffer);
const signature = genkey.sign(new Uint8Array(hashUint8Array))
const result = genkey.verify(hashUint8Array, signature)
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had faced a similar issue while using hdkey.  Function sign expects a Uint8Array(32) [or equivalent] as input.  My intent was to validate sign/verify and so I was simply looking for an input that could be passed accordingly.

Here's what I got working eventually:

```
console.log('Attempting sign n verify...')
const txnObj = { 
    from: 'abc', 
to: 'xyz'
}
console.log('txnObj:', txnObj);
const txnStr = JSON.stringify(txnObj);
console.log('txnStr:', txnStr);
const txnHash = sha256(txnStr);
console.log('txnHash:', txnHash);
const txnBuffer = Buffer.from(txnHash.toString(), 'hex');
console.log('txnBuffer:', txnBuffer);
const hashedUint8Array = new Uint8Array(txnBuffer);
console.log('hashUint8Array:', hashedUint8Array);
```

Here's the outcome:
[Outcome of executing above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dak6I.jpg)

Additionally, your signing prv and pub keys are not traceable in the provided code.

```
const hash = "Adadadas"
genkey.sign(hash)
hdkey.verify(hash, sign)
```

Suggest changing them as below ie. sign using your privKey and verify using your pubKey:

```
const hash = "Adadadas"
const signed = privKey.sign(hash)
pubKey.verify(hash, signed)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as bip39 from 'bip39'
import HdKey from 'hdkey'

function generateKeys(): HdKey {
  const mnemonicSeed = bip39.generateMnemonic()
  const seed = bip39.mnemonicToSeedSync(mnemonicSeed)
  const wallet = HdKey.fromMasterSeed(seed)
  return wallet
}

async function digestMessage(message: string) {
  const encoder = new TextEncoder()
  const data = encoder.encode(message)
  const hash = await crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-256', data)
  return Buffer.from(hash)
}

  // main
  const wallet = generateKeys()
  console.log(wallet.privateExtendedKey)
  console.log(wallet.publicExtendedKey)

  const message = 'Hello Ramzi'
  const hash = await digestMessage(message)
  console.log('hash', hash.toString('hex'))

  const signature = wallet.sign(hash)
  console.log('signature', signature.toString('hex'))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).